# To find Pebble by phone?

Tags: pebble

Assume you lost your Pebble watch in somewhere your room. You can find it by asking someone calling you but assume you cannot do it. You just have your Android phone.

### Find My Pebble Application

I think the application does not work. You install the application. I appears under your Applications in your phone. The front-end of the application contains only Settings and Delete. Settings does not work. You cannot Find your application by the app. You have to each time install and uninstall the application to find your Pebble. I think this kind of logic stupid. I am using Pebble Classing with Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-i9506 Android 5.0.1 Lollipop. Similar problem of the application also recorded [here](https://forums.getpebble.com/discussion/12797/watchapp-find-my-pebble)

> Agreed that not having to unload and load would improve the concept.

The front-end of the application is also buggy, crashing to open the Pebble-settings page too to get the view "Settings/Delete" in your phone.

---

How can you find your Pebble smartwatch with your Android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the application **Find Watch** more stable than **Find My Pebble**. 
It is also more popular in the community by ranking.

Answer (score 0):

Download "Find my Pebble" from the applications store inside the Pebble app. It will do what you have asked by blinking the backlight and vibrating.

Comment: I updated the body of the question and reviewed the application. I think it is rather immature.